# How to make a menu not collapse unless clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav_menu-5 li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('#nav_menu-5 li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

[my html code](http://pastebin.com/5CzgNAR0) 
I have the above code to make an unordered list do this:
[image]

I want the list to only open when clicked on and then stay open and only close when clicked on.

If you need more information please comment.

Edit 1: Added related HTML
Edit 2: I tried changing `hover()` to `click()` and that didn't work. It just made the page glitch.

Comment: show the related html markup

Comment: my bad, added the code in a pastebin link just below the jQuery

Comment: This is worth taking a look at. No need for any javascript to do this, just a simple checkbox hack: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: `.click()` is how you achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/fLa534je/

Comment: @VinnyM Oh, I see what I did wrong. The categories are linked so it just causes a page reload. Thanks.

Comment: @mhodges Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Yeah, the `preventDefault()` will be your ticket to success, but the answer below shows a solid way to achieve it.

Comment: @VinnyM, Thanks for your help regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work with jQuery, here's a way to do so:

```
$(function () {
  $('#nav_menu-5 li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');

  //when a lower-level submenu link is clicked, don't
  //allow the event to bubble up to the ancestor li
  $('#nav_menu-5 .menu > li li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  })

  //when a link is clicked, toggle the nested ul, and prevent
  //the default action of the link
  $('#nav_menu-5 .menu > li').click(function (e) {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here's a forked version of your codepen with this added: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZBPrR

Comment: *Awesome!* Now, is there any way that I can get the opened menu to collapse when I go to open another menu?

Comment: Sure. You can `slideUp` the other `.sub-menu:visible` items, and `slideToggle` the one you clicked. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNGZZE

Comment: That makes sense. You're seriously awesome, thank you!

Comment: Add `$('#nav_menu-5 .menu > li > ul').slideUp();` to the 2nd .click() function. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxYaOJ